# Unity best practices for unloading unused areas of a map

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm wondering about the best way of reducing my CPU and memory overhead for areas of the game world that do not need to be updated every frame.

I have just started to consider this issue as I'm currently implementing a shadow detection system using Raycasts.

My problem is this:

- I can have about 100 lights in my level that on every frame send a Raycast to nearby characters to determine if these characters are in shadows.

My game is a low poly PC game, and I understand the overhead from Raycasting isn't that drastic. So its not a major concern. But I'm still not sure of the best approach to optimising this.

I have been thinking of a few soltions, but am unsure if there is "standard" per say.

## 1. exit update loop if player is too far away

```cs
void Update() {
   if (Vector3.Distance(playerPos, transform.position) > someRadius) {
       return
   }
}
```

This is the most glaringly obvious solution, with even more obvious concerns.

1. This update loop will still be hogging CPU cycles , performing 2 calculations on every frame, for every light point.

## 2. Disable Light gameObjects when the player is too far away

This method is more efficient in terms of CPU overhead, as those will be negated. However I'm still hogging uneccesary memory.

In order to make this solution more scalable I would have to design some kind of "enabler" that keeps track of game objects that should be enabled/disabled based on the player position.

But at this point I know I'm re-inventing the wheel, and feel very sure that there is an industry standard for this.

Is there an alternative to enabling/disabling?

I see a lot of game developers talking about physically unloading areas of their game from memory and writing those areas to disk, when the player is not nearby.

I wonder is this achieved by simply destroying and re-instantiating the objects.

#### Question

Is Unity opionated about this?

The page [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity8.html) lists an example, similar to my first solution. But they are talking about 100s of thousands of updates per frame here.

Maybe I don't need to worry as much as I think

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered occlusion which is worked out on where your camera is, and only shows that which is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want not render objects, that are not in your camera area, **Occlusion culling** is what you exactly need. Watch this link:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

If You want change how your object looks based on range between camera and your object, You have to use **LOD(Level Of Detail)**. Here is documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LODGroup.html